# How to use variables in SELECT?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, view, db2, global-variables

I use IBM® Data Studio V4.1.0.1, DB2 v10.5.

This is my stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test ()
    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
P1: BEGIN
    DECLARE ageInterval INTEGER;

    SELECT (MAX("age")-min("age"))/5
    INTO ageInterval 
    FROM "Schema1"."adult";   


create view "DiscreteTrain" as 
select 
"age"/ageInterval,
"income"
from "Schema1"."train";

END P1
```

When I deploy it, data studio says **DB2ADMIN.TEST: 15: "AGEINTERVAL" is not valid in the context where it is used. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=3.67.28**

How should I use the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use this variable in a view.  According to the [documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/sqlp/rbafycrtvar.htm):

> Global variables can be used in any context where an expression is
>   allowed. Unlike a host variable, a global variable can be used in a
>   CREATE VIEW statement.

So, you have some options.  You can switch the variable to a global variable by using `create variable`.  Or, you can do the calculation each time:

```
create view "DiscreteTrain" as 
    select  "age"/a.ageInterval as MyAge, "income"
    from "Schema1"."train" cross join
         (SELECT (MAX("age")-min("age"))/5 as ageInterval
          FROM "Schema1"."adult"
         ) a;
```

Comment: Is there any significance to using a cross join rather than an inner join with a single row subquery?

Comment: @WarrenT . . . I prefer the `cross join` because I can define multiple variables at the same time.  Also, in some databases, the single row subquery might be executed for each row.