# DB2 use LIKE clause in view with a Global Variable

Tags: sql, view, db2, global-variables, db2-400

We have a VIEW we created in I-series DB2 that fetches data based on a GLOBAL VARIABLE that has been created and set previous to running the statement:

It is a great performance increase, but only seems to work using an equals clause:

```
SET myvariable='foo';
where field = myvariable;
```

However I am trying to match using a LIKE clause similar to:

```
SET myvariable='%foo%';
WHERE field LIKE myvariable;
```

I have also tried the following, concatenating the % signs:

```
SET myvariable='foo';
WHERE field LIKE '%' || myvariable || '%';
```

Neither of the LIKE methods are working and I cannot find any examples online of how to use a Global Variable in a LIKE clause, all examples are only for Equals clauses.

Any ideas how to make this match work?

Comment: try using `LOCATE()` http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000820.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-3-2-79

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use variables in SELECT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22426278/how-to-use-variables-in-select)

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: There were no errors, just a blank recordset being returned.  I found the underlying issue and added an answer.  Thanks for the input!

Comment: @Bulat This was not a duplicate.  There were no errors in my context or setting of the variable.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem!

The variable being created was a CHAR type instead of a VARCHAR type, so the value needed to be trimmed before concatenating the % signs on either side.  Alternatively, I could have changed it to type VARCHAR